# In miller rabin algorithm in check function in while loop why we use " x = mod(x, x, n) " this?

Tags: c++, algorithm

code full link : [Full Code link](https://aranik43.blogspot.com/2020/06/miller-rabin-primality-test.html)

```
bool check(ll a, ll d, ll n)
{
  ll x = power(a, d, n);

  if (x == 1 || x == n - 1)
    return true;

  while (d != n - 1) 
  {
    x = mod(x, x, n);
    d = (d << 1); /*** d = d * 2 ***/

    if (x == 1)
      return false;
    if (x == n - 1)
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you give some text explaining your problem and what you don't understand? Or maybe even beter, what you expected the algorithm to do and what it does that confuses you.

Answer (score 1):

The `mod` function is badly named -- it should be called `mul` or `mulmod` -- `mod(a, b, n)` computes a*b modulo n.

So `mod(x, x, n)` is just squaring x.